# Is this expression OK? $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it OK to write $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$?

I thought it should be written as $\frac{d(xy)}{dx}=x\frac{dy}{dx}+y$ to clarify with respect to which variable the equation is differentiated.
Is the first expression widely accepted in mathematics?

What would happen if you combine it with an integral?
$\int{\frac{d(xy)}{dx}dx}=\int{d(xy)}=xy$?

Comment: It does make sense.

Comment: @Tavish how about the integral form? Does it also make sense?

Comment: @Tavish It should be a function of x I think

Comment: If it is, then $xy$ is also a function of $x$ and what you wrote is correct.

Comment: In the context where $x,y$ are regarded just as coordinate functions, the first expression is accepted as an equation of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), although this is a bit beyond the topic of ordinary calculus.